# How supported old browsers with create react app

Tags: reactjs

I need used my React App on old computer (Win XP + old browser). XP notsupported new browser. Default installing - old browser version (chrome, opera, firefox). I suspect, that old browser not supported ES6 syntax (main.chunk.js). How fixed this?

[image]

If fixed this error, will appear new error. Eg let is a reserved identifier (everything related to ES6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely need to polyfill the unsupported features of newer javascript.

For React projects I use [react-app-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill)

Follow the instructions for installing into your project and then in your root `index.js` file import the polyfills ***before all other imports***.

Here's an example:

```
// using ie9 polyfills as the "kitchen sink" of polyfills
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
// ... the rest of your imports
import React from 'react';
...
```

For other unsupported esX features check out the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for the javascript function you are attempting to use to see if they also provide polyfill implementations, for example [Array reduce polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

I found that above answer when I'm searching the same question. So, I think that question is need to details about the question.

According to the [**Mozilla**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) documentation:

> A polyfill is a piece of code (usually JavaScript on the Web) used to provide modern functionality on older browsers that do not natively support it.

If your browser does not support new JavaScript features like the `import`, `arrow function` etc. (which is in my case) statement, it may not be possible to run a ReactJS app directly in that browser. However, Using a polyfill like **Babel** or **Webpack** or maybe **Browserify** we could that takes multiple JavaScript files and combines them into a single file that can be executed by a browser.